# Web Query from Google Sheet only returning 100 rows

Tags: vba, web, google-sheets, rows

I am currently running the following Web Query to return 3000+ rows of data from a google sheet I use. Unfortunately when I run it it only returns 100 rows of data. Is there anyway to extend its capabilities to pull the full 3000 rows of data?

```
Sub Basic_Web_Query()
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.....", 
Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
.Name = "q?s=goog_2"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
 .SavePassword = False
 .SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebTables = "1,2"
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: is it all one table or multiple tables?

Comment: It is one table

Comment: what happens with web selection type set to xlEntirePage

Comment: It still only exports 100 row, just in a slightly different format